# Updating a Pasted range

Tags: excel, vba

I have about 30 sheets each representing a day of the week. This would save me a huge amount of time.

I have had a look in this room for problem similar to mine, but I have had no luck.

I am keen to get some help.

So the problem; I have tried to amend the below code but with no luck as I get error messages.

I am trying to copy the same data, with a slight twist.

However I want the date column, "A" which is the "same date" for each cell from A2-A85, when its pasted it goes up by 1 day every time.

The end outcome should be 7 different days consecutively when it is pasted 7 times but each time its going up.

At this moment the code allows me to copy and paste 7 times the same data.

Your help and insight would be appreciated

```
' this is just one sheet    

Sub CopyRange()

Dim rws As Long

Sheets("20160817").Activate
With Worksheets("20160817").Range("A2:O85")
rws = .Rows.Count + 2
  .Resize(rws).Copy Destination:=.Offset(rws).Resize(rws * 7)
End With
End Sub
```

Many thanks,

Please note, in order to get the ranges for these thirty sheets, I have had to use the concantation function and count, to work out the number of rows for each sheet. The columns is fixed A-O. In order to work out my range code.

Kind regards
Ali

```
Col
A     B       C             D    .......O
16/9  Data1B   Data1C   Data1D
16/9  Data2B   Data2C   Data2D
.
.
16/9  Data2B   Data2C   Data2D

code run

Col
A     B       C             D    .......O
17/9  Data1B   Data1C   Data1D
17/9  Data2B   Data2C   Data2D
.
.
17/9  Data2B   Data2C   Data2D
```

Continues X times the date going up by one from the previous date

Comment: You're using `rws` to resize the range, but note that `rws` will never change. It will always be `83` (or the rows in range `A2:O85`.  Perhaps you can add `Dim i as Long // i = 0` then do `rws = .Rows.Count + 2 + i`, and add `i = i+1` after the resize line?

Comment: @BruceWayne, `rws`  mustn't change since the `Resize(rws * 7)` in the `Destination` parameter will take care of _extending_ the copied range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Sub CopyRange()
    Dim rws As Long

    With Worksheets("20160817").Range("A2:O85")
        rws = .Rows.Count + 2
        With .Resize(rws)
            .Copy Destination:=.Offset(rws).Resize(rws * 7)
            .Offset(rws).Resize(rws * 7, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) = "=R[-86]c+1"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

BTW, you don't need any `Activate`

Comment: Your code is not working, please note, that once I copy this data, be it 7 or x times, the date must change or move up by 1, so if its pasted 7 times, it would move up by 7

Comment: I tested it. So please be more detailed about what "not working means" with respect to desired behaviour

Comment: Can you tell me what the additional bit of your code is doing?

Comment: Which line throws that error? My code adds a formula in all column A pasted cells that takes the number at the corresponding cell of the preceeding block and adds 1 to it

Comment: I have checked its last bit of the code, and the date is not moving up by one, I am not sure why you have have a if formula with reference to column O?

Comment: Column A has the date, that the column that should be changing everytime the values are pasted by one. Please note I am not asking you to add additional line after, I am asking for the date to be move up by one.

Comment: Formula has no reference to column O. It has reference to a cell that's 86 rows up and in the same column of the cell it's writing in. And this latter are all column A cell of pasted cells, since the (,-1) part of the Resize method narrows down the range it's called upon to its first column. Which line throws the error.

Comment: And my formula has no "IF". Are you trying my code, actually?

Comment: Sorry I was using the wrong file, your code is working but not correctly,  why is it adding from A47 + 1,  and not A2 + 1, for the first paste and as its out of sequence

Comment: Sub CopyRange()
    Dim rws As Long
    With Worksheets("20160104").Range("A2:O130")
        rws = .Rows.Count + 2
        With .Resize(rws)
            .Copy Destination:=.Offset(rws).Resize(rws * 7)
            .Offset(rws).Resize(rws * 7, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) = "=R[-130]c+1"
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Comment: The range and sheet I am using is different for the sheet and its not working, its just doing copy and paste now, I think your r formula was the item which was changing the date

Comment: Sorry mate it works, it was me, as I had to close the file several times as the column a has formulas, to rerun the code

Comment: To accept an answer click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thank you